# Dynamic Route with Google Directions API: Getting route on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The route path is not getting generated on click of destination.

```
function calcRoute() {
    var request = {
        origin: geolocate,
        destination: destLoc,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode["Driving"]
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Wrishi/w8n7p7sf/

Please help me identify the problem.

Comment: See the javascript console: `Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property travelMode: undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong value in definition of travelMode. Here is a correct one: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING

Correct request will be as following:

```
  var request = {
    origin: geolocate,
    destination: destLoc,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8n7p7sf/1/)

Comment: God bless you Thor... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 middleLeg  = {   origin: address1,
                    destination : address2,
                    travelMode  :   google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING

},
```

Comment: When  you add an answer please try to explain what is wrong and how this code fixes it.